# Choosing what partition to install ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

From my experience with installing Ubuntu, I have never been able to physically choose which partition the OS is installed on. As long as I had an unallocated partition, it did the job. However, I want to install Ubuntu on a currently occupied partition. So in order to overwrite this partition with Ubuntu, how can I select which partition Ubuntu gets installed on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you need is in the **Something else** option when you reach the partitioning menu during the installation process.  In there you can select the existing partition you want to use, erase the current contents and instruct the installer to mount it as root partition.

This is not the only thing you need to do though since you probably need to create a swap partition too and select a place to install grub.  If you are not familiar with these tasks, [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation) may help you.

**Backup all your data** before you start this process since there is a great chance you might make unrecoverable mistakes.  Be very careful.

Comment: I currently have Lubuntu installed in the partitions right now, so grub is already installed. So all I need to do is just select the partition right?

Comment: The installer will install grub anyway.  If you chose the automatic installation when you installed lubuntu and you didn't place it elsewhwre manually, your current grub installation will be overwritten unless you choose to install it on another partition this time which I would not recommend personally.  Out of curiosity, is it a dual boot system we are talking about?  Is there a specific reason why you don't want to do a full installation?

Comment: I currently have Lubuntu 16.04 installed on my partition, and its full of bugs. So I want to replace it with good ol' Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. And yes, it is a dual boot with Windows 10 Pro

Comment: Ok.  The link I gave you above also contains a dual boot specific section.  You can also delete the current lubuntu partition from Windows if you feel more comfortable with it.  Ubuntu installer will find the unpartitioned space again and follow the procedure you are already familiar with.

Comment: I was thinking about doing that. You think that would be the safer option?

Comment: Unless you know exactly what to do with manual partitioning using the Ubuntu installer, yes, I do.  It totally depends on you.  Do not delete the lubuntu partition from Windows without proceeding with the new installation though.  You have to uninstall grub too.  You will find instructions for removing it too on this link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40220/discussion-between-dhaneku-b-and-stormlord).